# Is there a leaner way to write multiline code in Twig templates?

Tags: twig

If I have a block of code like this:

```
{% if app.user is defined %}
    {% set isOwner = user.isEqualTo(app.user) %}
{% else %}
    {% set isOwner = false %}
{% endif %}
```

Is it possible to write it without wrapping every line in tags, like this?

```
{% if app.user is defined
    set isOwner = user.isEqualTo(app.user)
else
    set isOwner = false
endif %}
```

The above code obviously doesn't work, because there are no line terminators. Adding a `;` doesn't work either.

If there are a lot of lines, things get really complicated.

**Update:**

While DarkBee's answer is the way to shorten the syntax, be wary of passing null to a method that may be expecting an object of a particular class. The final version of the code we eventually went with is not much better than the original question, but at least it's one less line:

```
{% set isOwner = false %}
{% if app.user is not null %}
    {% set isOwner = user.isEqualTo(app.user) %}
{% endif %}
```

This way, the boolean flag is always set and the method never receives a null object.

Also, if you're worried about extra spaces creeping into your HTML (as a result of the indentation), the best way to avoid that is to wrap that whole piece of code in `{% spaceless %}...{% endspaceless %}` tags.

Comment: @DarkBee That's also very interesting!

Comment: @DarkBee I wish you had posted this as an answer!

Comment: Be careful what you whish for

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A shorter way to do this is:

```
{% set isOwner = user.isEqualTo(app.user|default(null)) %}
```

Comment: But this is not multiline code. Should we assume that it is not possible?

Comment: @Fernando Not sure what you are asking? Original code snippet was multiline and OP wanted a leaner (shorter?) method

Comment: Thanks @DarkBee, might be I misunderstood the question. What I mean is that your code is not "leaner multiline code" but "leaner single line code". I came to this question looking for a way to write several lines without wraping every one of them inside brackets, and that is what I meant with my comment, if that is possible or not.

Comment: @Fernando could be you are looking for [{% set %}...{% endset %}](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46098990/how-to-print-twig-variables-inside-html-code/46099342#46099342)

Answer (score 3):

I think no, you can use a ternary operator like:

```
{% set isOwner = (app.user is defined  and user.isEqualTo(app.user)) ? true : false %}
```

Hope this help

More info [here](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/2.x/templates.html#other-operators) in the doc

Comment: No need to place `? true : false` at the end though