# How to print twig variables inside html code

Tags: php, symfony, variables, twig

I created a variable, like this :

```
{% set checkboxHTML = '<button class="btn btn-default btn-md" data-id="{{b.id}}">Edit</button>' %}
```

Now I trying print in two ways:

1. `{{ checkboxHTML }}`

Above it printed like text (no html)

2. `{{ checkboxHTML | raw }}`

Print the html, but the variable `{{ b.id }}` doesn't take it like twig sintax, take it like text

How to print that variable inside a text ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Alternative method to solve this is using the expanded `{% set %}`
Do note when using this method, the content is considered being safe

```
{% set checkboxHTML %}
    <button class="btn btn-default btn-md" data-id="{{ b.id }}">Edit</button>
{% endset %}
```

[twigfiddle](https://twigfiddle.com/n1zrwd)

Answer (score 4):

You have to use set, like this:

```
{% set checkboxHTML = '<button class="btn btn-default btn-md" data-id="' ~ b.id ~ '">Edit</button>' %}
```

Documentation: https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/tags/set.html

Comment: sorry, I use set, I forgot put it, but event though doesn't work

Comment: @JoseAlejandroRamirezRivera ok, I edited and added how you can add variable, you use `~`