# Twig Raw with Twig

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I've a little bit problem.

i want to use twig syntax inside a variable who is display in raw (twigception :))

Exemple :

```
{{ set myvar = "<img src='{% theme('/img/logo.png') %}' />" }}
<div class='mylogo'>{% myvar|raw %}</div>
```

But, the render is:

```
<div class='mylogo'><img src='{% theme('/img/logo.png') %}' />
```

I want that {% theme('/img/logo.png') %} interpreted by twig but i don't know how i can do that and if it's possible, if you can help me please

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to print twig variables inside html code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46098990/how-to-print-twig-variables-inside-html-code)

Answer (score 0):

You have to concat your variable, otherwise twig will read it as text.

try something like

```
{% set myvar = "<img src='"~ theme('/img/logo.png') ~"' />" %}
<div class='mylogo'>{% myvar|raw %}</div>
```

Comment: `~{%` is invalid though