# Twig raw with twig (2)

Tags: symfony, tags, twig

I have a similar problem as [set-default-raw-filter-in-twig](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22185878/set-default-raw-filter-in-twig) and [twig-raw-with-twig](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46194112/twig-raw-with-twig), but in different way.
I use two tables of my Data Base.

The first one, `edition`  contains dates in DateTime format, to use as deadlines of our competition.
Here, the property `dateouverturesite` has the value `2021-05-08 00:00:00`

The second one, `odpf_article` contains texts to be used in my render. Thats text are formatted with HTML tags.

In one of these text, I hope to schow the dates from the first table. I tried to put these references as Twig variables : Twig in Twig !

My function in the Symfony Controller :

```
    public function concours(Request $request,$choix): \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response
        {
            $edition = $this->session->get('edition');
            $repo2=$this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(OdpfArticle::class);
            $article=$repo2->findOneBy(['choix'=>$choix]);
            $texte=$article->getTexte();
            $tab=[ 'choix'=>$choix,
                  'texte'=>$texte,
                  'edition'=>$edition ];
            return $this->render('core/odpf-concours.html.twig', $tab);
        }
```

Some lines in the `texte` property

```
     <p><strong>PHASE D’INSCRIPTION</strong></p>
     <ul>  
       <li> ouverture des inscriptions :{{app.session.get('edition').date_ouverture_site}} </li> 
       <li>{{app.session.get('edition').date_cloture_inscriptions}}
     <span style="color: red;"><strong>(heure de Paris)</strong></span>
     : clôture des inscriptions
       </li> 
    </ul>
```

The lines of the render :

```
                <div class ="contenu">
                    {{ texte|escape('html') }}
                </div>
```

Or with the raw filter :

```
                <div class ="contenu">
                    {{ texte|raw }}
                </div>
```

And the final result (the same for both filters:
`**PHASE D’INSCRIPTION**`
`ouverture des inscriptions :{{ app.session.get('edition').dateouverturesite }}`
`**(heure de Paris)**`

My question is : how can I write my Twig variable ?

I have ten differents dates to show, in the same `texte`, and another filter to apply to show only the month and the day...

My answer to the link provide by DarkBee is that  :

1. I changed my line for `{{ include(template_from_string(texte)) }}`
2. The Exception was :`Object of class DateTime could not be converted to string`
3. So, I wrote my template line `{{date(app.session.get('edition').dateouverturesite)}}`
4. And I had the same Exception...

Comment: So you have `twig` stored inside the database?

Comment: @DarkBee : What is in my Database is the content of a mix of HTML and Twig variables :  <p><strong>PHASE D’INSCRIPTION</strong></p>
<ul>
<li> ouverture des inscriptions :{{app.session.get('edition').date_ouverture_site}}  </li>
<li>{{app.session.get('edition').date_cloture_inscriptions}} <span style="color: red;"><strong>(heure de Paris)</strong></span> : clôture des inscriptions</li>
</ul>

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to render Twig template from database in symfony2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8188674/how-to-render-twig-template-from-database-in-symfony2)

Comment: @DarkBee  Thanks but I've tried for hours to adapt it, and... no change !

Comment: Then please update the question the new attempts you've made. Also especially check out this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23956895/446594) in the question I've linked

Comment: @DarkBee I had first tried to adapt the other answer with 'Create the Template Entity` ...

Comment: You'll have to add the date filter behind the DateTime variable in the template in your database e.g. `Date modified {{ myDate|date('d-m-Y') }}` - anyway that's an entirely different issue than the first question you've asked. As you are receiving this (new) error, it seems your first question was solved. If you have any more question, feel free to post a new question

Answer (score 0):

You have to concatenate the variable with the the string using the tilde `"string" ~ var ~ "more string"`

```html
{% set something = 'stuff' %}
{% set texte = '<ul>
      <li> ouverture des inscriptions :' ~ something ~ ' 
      </li>
    </ul>' %}
    
{{ texte|raw }}
```

result:

```html
<ul>
    <li> ouverture des inscriptions :stuff 
    </li>
</ul>
```

However, I suspect that what you really want to do is use a template fragment, especially if the inserted values may change.

```html
{# src: _fragment.html.twig #}
    <ul>
      <li> ouverture des inscriptions :{{ app.session.get('edition').date_ouverture_site }}  
      </li>
    </ul>
```

Then include it wherever you want as many times as needed

```html
{# src: main.html.twig #}

<div>
  <h1>The list:</h1>
  {{ include('_fragment.html.twig') }}
</div>

<div>
  <h4>That list again:</h4>
  {{ include('_fragment.html.twig') }}
</div>
```

Comment: If you want to store `HTML` in a variable it's more convenient to use `{% set var %}...{% endset %}` - [demo](https://twigfiddle.com/z6gxm8)

Comment: @Arleigh Hix : It's very difficult : I have to include 10 differents dates inside of the same text (see an exemple in my answer to the comment of DarkBee)